# Python -V for 2.7.3 tells me 2.7.15

Tags: python, python-2.7

So without going in the details of why I need to do this. I've done the following;

- Installed python 2.7.15 (64bit, Windows)
- Installed python 2.7.3 (64bit, Windows)

I've created cmd files called python27-15 & python27-3 that should let me call the version I want.

My problem is that even if I am in the directory of the installed python version `2.7.3`, and open `python.exe`. The version it prints to cmd is `2.7.15` and not `2.7.3`.

I thought I might have actually installed the wrong version, but I've checked that the `READ ME` file in the install directory, says `2.7.3`.

I've also checked in the `Add or Remove Programs` settings of windows, that there are 2 versions of Python installed (`2.7.3` and `2.7.15`).

How can this happen?

**EDIT**

In `%PATH%` I have the directories of both installation.

The path of `2.7.15` is listed first, so as expected, `python -V`  in any directory will give me `2.7.15`.

But if I `cd` to the directory of `2.7.3`, `python -V` will give me `2.7.15` as well.

Explicitly opening the `python.exe` file in the directory of `2.7.3` will also print out `Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26)`.

Comment: Side question: is there any particular reason you need version 2.7.3 instead of 2.7.15? The latter is exactly the same, just with a lot more bug fixes.

Comment: I'm using a software (Abaqus) which comes with python `2.7.3` to allow you to create plugins. I ran into some trouble, and want to test myself by comparing some scripts with `2.7.3` and `2.7.15`.

Comment: Why not make sure that they are completely seperate by using virtual environments? Also try typing `where python` to see which python.exe is being found

Comment: I think it could be %PATH% problem. What is happens when You type `python -V`. 
I expect `2.7.15`

Comment: `where python` will give me 3 pythons (the ones that are in the two directories of version 2.7.15 and 2.73, and a third one, which is in the Abaqus directory.) The 2.7.15 is listed first. If I `where python` in the directory of python 2.7.3, the version 2.7.3 will come first.

Comment: @3sky I edited the post.

Comment: What if you remove the path for python 2.7.15 just remain the path for python 2.7.3? Just see any magic?

Comment: @atline , good idea, and this is weird. I removed the `2.7.15` from path. `where python` will give me only the path of `2.7.3`, but `python -V `still gives  `2.7.15`.

Double clicking on `2.7.3` executable, also still gives `2.7.15`. Starting to thing it a mistake from the installation file...

Comment: I guess the python2.7.3 binary was falsely updated to 2.7.15 binary although it currently in the folder python2.7.3. So the output just give you the correct info, as it said I am python2.7.15 binary now, although I am in python2.7.3 folder. You had to do a clean install I think.

Comment: @atline and what would you mean by clean install? I just installed it and it re-installed it recently.

Comment: If you don't care why it happen, just want to get rid of this issue. Just remove all python you installed, do a fresh install for what you needed version.

Comment: ok, thanks @atline. And a side question (if allowed in comment). Is there any reason why pythonnet, specifically `clr`, would have trouble in 2.7.3 and not in 2.7.15?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a .NET programmer, never touch it. Suggest to new a post to ask the question.